# Give user access only to one field - Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am building an API using Django Rest Framework for my car-sharing app. I want to let not owner users to have access to update "participants" field in race, so they can join. Other fields should be available only to owner. I was reading about [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but i don't realy understand how to implement it. Here's my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Race(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", related_name = 'races', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    origin_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)  
    origin_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    destination_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    destination_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    start_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)
    schedule = models.DurationField(blank=True,null=True)
    subs = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subs',blank=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you checking whether the user is owner or not?
Is it by using auth_groups ?

Comment: Now i only give users access to modify their own race and other one can see it. Heres my function.                                                          class OwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
    return obj.owner == request.user

Comment: Ok. So you modified the scenario so as to adjust your need.

Though my code will work for the given scenario that was asked in the question.
You can try it and accept it so that others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Django has anyway to have field level permission by default.

But we can tweak and restrict the fields through the `serializers.py` and `views.py` .

In `views.py`

```
class RaceUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = RaceUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Race.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    model = Race

    def put(self, request, pk):
        try:
            try:
                race_obj = self.get_object()
            except Exception as error:
                context = {'error': "Race Id does not exist", 'success': "false", 'message': 'Race Id does not exist.'}
                return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

            #I don't know how you are checking owner. So i kept it this way.
            if request.user.id != race_obj.owner.id:
                #passing the fields which are to be used by the serializer.
                serializer = RaceUpdateSerializer(race_obj, data=request.data, partial=True, fields=('participants',))
            else:
                serializer = RaceUpdateSerializer(race_obj, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                try:
                    serializer.save()
                except Exception as error:
                    context = {"success": False, "message": "Update Failed. %s" % str(error), "error": str(error)}
                    return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                context = {"success": True, "message": "Updated Successful", "error": "", "data": serializer.data}
                return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            context = {"success": False, "message": "Updated Failed, Invalid Input Data", "error": str(serializer.errors)}
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as error:
            context = {'error': str(error), 'success': "false", 'message': 'Failed To Update Race.'}
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

In `serializers.py`

```
class RaceUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Race
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(RaceUpdateSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

This way only the mentioned fields which is called from the `views.py` will be used while updating.

```
serializer = RaceUpdateSerializer(race_obj, data=request.data, partial=True, fields=('participants',))
```

It will achieve the task that you are trying to do.

**Note** - You can allow multiple fields this way as well

```
serializer = RaceUpdateSerializer(race_obj, data=request.data, partial=True, fields=('field1','field2'))
```